# How to set value in a hidden field and hide a div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am newbie to javascript 
and i want to know how to set value in a hidden field using java script
and how to hide a div using java script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to set value in a hidden field
>   using java script

**Set the value for hidden field:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('hidden field id');
el.value = 'some value';
```

> and how to hide a div using java
>   script

**Hide a div:**

```
var el2 = document.getElementById('div id');
el2.style.display = 'none';
```

You might want to peform either of those actions if some element gets clicked, you could do:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('button id');

btn.onclick = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('hidden field id');
    el.value = 'some value';
}
```

where id can be set for an element like this:

```
<div id="myid">
```

Have a look at:

- [JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp)

Comment: and what about showing a hidden div, how to do so ?

Comment: @sword101: See how we had hidden it `el2.style.display = 'none';` To show it use: `el2.style.display = 'block';`